# MVC AddObject Create multiple records

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, list

I have a list which contains multiple records. I like to use the AddObject to create those records but what is happening is that it creates just the last record in the list.

Here is the code

```
    foreach (var item in invlist) {

         invmodel.tblrec.FirstName = item.FirstName;
         invmodel.tblrec.LastName = item.LastName;

         db.tblRec.AddObject(invmodel.tblrec);                         

     }

     db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with this very simple modification of your code:

```
foreach (var item in invlist) {

     var tblRec = new TblRec(); 
     tblRec.FirstName = item.FirstName;
     tblRec.LastName = item.LastName;

     db.tblRec.AddObject(tblRec);                         

 }

 db.SaveChanges();
```

Why? Because your code is repeatedly adding the same instance and for EF it is still the same object - it will either result in exception or only the last item will be inserted to database.